# how to change row color as selected while clicking on edit icon button with jquery /javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have table which collect the data from DB, i want to highlight the row when click the selected row for edit the selected row will be highlight.

### Table Selecting (Edit By ID)

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Title</th>
                                    <th>Detail</th>
                                    <th>Image</th>                                      
                                    <th>created</th>                                        
                                    <th>Action</th>                                     
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php if(!empty($servicedata)): foreach($servicedata as $service): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $service['id']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $service['title']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo (strlen($service['detail'])>150)?substr($service['detail'],0,10).'...':$service['detail']; ?></td>
                                        <td><img scr="<?php echo $service['userfile']; ?>" class="img-recponsive" stlye="width:50px;"></td> 
                                        <td><?php echo $service['created']; ?></td>                                         
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="<?php echo base_url("admin/service/edit/".$service['id']);?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="change_Row_Highlight();">Edit </a>
                                            <a href="<?php echo base_url("admin/service/delete/".$service['id']);?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">Delete</a>
                                        </td>                                           
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; else: ?>
                                <tr><td colspan="6">Record(s) not found......</td></tr>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

### jquery code

```
 function change_Row_Highlight() {
   $('.table tbody tr').addcss('background-color':'#ddd;');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like `addcss` in jquery. Use `addClass` or just `.css` like

```
 function change_Row_Highlight() {
  $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color' , '#ddd');
 }
```

To get the reference of clicked element, use `this` and as you want to add some css to the `tr`. You can get the parent `tr` with `.closest('tr')`

Comment: Thank you for your reply i change the function as per your instructions but it still not works...

Comment: It was not works but i do it with php by selecting ID Thank You! you kind efforts and support... <3